# How to handle unknown/invalid binding routing key values in RabbitMQ?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq, amqp, spring-cloud-stream

I'd like to know what is the best way to handle messages with unknown/invalid routing key values inside an exchange?
In my case, I'm sending all my messages inside the same exchange and based on a routing key, messages are routed to the corresponding queue.
Here's my configuration (I'm using Spring Cloud Stream) :

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.destination: my-exchange
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.producer.routingKeyExpression: payload.type

spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input-type1.destination: my-exchange # Exchange
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input-type1.group: input.type1 # Queue 1
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input-type2.destination: my-exchange # Exchange
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input-type2.group: input.type2 # Queue 2

spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.input-type1.consumer.bindingRoutingKey: FOO
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.input-type2.consumer.bindingRoutingKey: BAR
```

Now what I'm asking is what happens if I send a message with `payload.type='ANY'`? Obviously, this message won't be retrieved by any consumer and will remain inside the exchange, but what is the best way to keep track of these "unknown" messages?  Can I use a DLQ for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> will remain inside the exchange,

No; exchanges don't "hold" messages, they are simply routers.

Unroutable messages are discarded by default.

You can configure the binding to return unroutable messages.

See [Error Channels](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit/docs/3.0.10.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit.html#rabbit-error-channels).

Returns are asynchronous.

In the upcoming 3.1 release, you can wait on a future to determine whether the message was sent successfully or not. See [Publisher Confirms](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit/docs/3.1.0-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit.html#publisher-confirms).

If the message is unroutable, the correlation data's `returnedMessage` property is set.

The framework uses the `mandatory` feature mentioned in another answer.

**EDIT**

Here is an example:

```
spring.rabbitmq.publisher-returns: true

spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.destination: my-exchange
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.output.producer.routing-key-expression: headers['rk']

spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.producer.error-channel-enabled: true
```

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBinding(Source.class)
public class So65134452Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So65134452Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(MessageChannel output) {
        return args -> {
            output.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload("foo")
                    .setHeader("rk", "invalid")
                    .build());
        };
    }

    @Autowired
    RabbitTemplate template;

    @Bean
    public Queue unroutable() {
        return new Queue("unroutable.messages");
    }

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "errorChannel")
    public void error(Message<?> error) {
        if (error.getPayload() instanceof ReturnedAmqpMessageException) {
            this.template.send(unroutable().getName(),
                    ((ReturnedAmqpMessageException) error.getPayload()).getAmqpMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on exchanges. In my case, I would like the message to be re-routed automatically to an alternate queue (an "unrouted" queue).  Is it what you meant by "configure the binding to return unroutable messages"?
Is it possible to configure this behavior using only Spring Cloud Stream? Do you happen to have an example on how to achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: @Fred There is nothing built in to do that but it is possible with a few lines of config and a little bit of Java. I will add an example in the morning, US east coast time.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot I'm looking forward to it... this example would be very appreciated.

Comment: Note that `errorChannel` gets errors from all bindings; if you have multiple output bindings and wish to send unroutables to different queues, use `@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "my-exchange.errors")` instead.

Comment: Another question, in my case my producer is in a different application than my 2 consumers, is it still possible to catch those unrouted messages within the consumer app or does it have to be on the producer side?

Comment: The republishing has to be done on the producer side (which is where the returned message is sent to); you can, of course, configure an consumer binding in your consumer app to receive the unroutable messages.

Comment: Just to make sure I get this right, I would still have to set `error-channel-enabled` and `publisher-returns` properties to `true` on the producer side and the error would still be returned inside the producer `errorChannel`.
And from there, I could send the message to a consumer binding in my consumer app.
Am I correct?

Answer (score 2):

You could use `mandatory` property for your [publishers](https://www.rabbitmq.com/publishers.html).

```
When a published message cannot be routed to any queue, 
and the publisher set the mandatory message property to true, the 
message will be returned to it.
The publisher must have a returned message handler set up in order to 
handle the return (e.g. by logging an error or retrying with a different exchange)
```

Comment: Setting up an alternate exchange seems to be exactly what I'm looking for. Could you share an example on how to do that using Spring Cloud Stream?

Comment: @Fred I've never worked with Spring Cloud Stream before. I represented the main concept. I guess Gary Russell can provide you an example.